# How do I use toCSS() in paper.js?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

Paper.js says it has a function toCSS(hex) which returns the color as a CSS string, either in hex or not.

http://paperjs.org/reference/color/#tocss-hex

Does anyone know how to use this I have had no luck and can find no examples.

I am trying to convert a var Color which =hit.item.fillcolor which appears to be a ctor.
If I try to use toCSS I get Color.toCSS is not a function.

The function above toCSS in the documentation - toString() works fine.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking but here is an issue.

The fill color is `item.fillColor`, not `item.fillcolor`, which is undefined.

That's why you get `Color.toCSS()` is not a function.

---

- `toCSS(false)` returns this format: "rgb(0,230,191)"
- `toCSS(true)` returns this format: "#00e6bf"

Comment: Thanks but I still can't do it - probably a brain fart - but: console.log(hit.item.fillColor.toCSS(true)) is returning an error

Comment: Without your code I can't see what the issue is. Here is a very simple paper sketch that shows it works - [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/jY69DsIwDAZfJcrSVKoisRYx5QWQMgJDSA2NEmLkmHZAvDspPwsTo++7k3yX2V1A9tJGYD/KTnoclntyJHwgn0BsRIZZbB2P2ryImgLM2kNmoE6s2vU+v1V9CikZTEg1+qDChBG+sCEYmurXAnPBuic8q99aMxprVdv+pTHdYFHr80cCF68YMhfZ7w6PJw==). I suspect that the problem is not toCSS().